# my python custom escape_html(s) function doesn't work (Udacity web development course)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web

I'm trying to write a function such that html elements will be preserved in html. My custom function below doesn't produce the correct output. Does anyone know why?

```
 def escape_html(s):
    for char in s:
        s.replace('>','%gt;')
        s.replace('<', '%lt;')
        s.replace('"','%quot;')
        s.replace('&', '%amp;')
    return s
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In python, string object is reference and the string it points to cannot be changed, so you should point s to another string as follows

PS:replace function will replace the entire string

```
def escape_html(s):
    s = s.replace('&','&amp;')
    s = s.replace('>','&gt;')
    s = s.replace('<','&lt;')
    s = s.replace('"','&quot;') 
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way of writing the function is:

```
import cgi

def escape_html(s):
  return cgi.escape(s, quote = True)
```